# SQL - how to find records with specific type in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql table with records having types A ,B and C. There are some records with only type B and C . How can I find the records with only type B and C using sql query ?

```
 Emp id  type 
 1         A 
 1         B
 1         C
 2         B
 2         C
 3         A
 3         C
 4         A
 4         B
```

so my query should return me employee id 2 as it doesn't have type A.

Comment: What have you tried? This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times. And this seems a lot like homework.

Comment: Expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a self join or a nested subselect:

```
select * from employees a
where type in ('B','C')
and not exists 
 (select 1 from employees b
  where a.id = b.id
  and b.type = 'A')
```

This will return all employee records that have types B or C, but not A.

Comment: Works, until you add a further type in.

Comment: this is not require "type in ('B','C')"

Comment: Can I use "Group By" before not exists?

Comment: The group by is one of the last clauses in a SQL statement. if you want to compute against a post-aggregated value, I think you're limited to comparison operators like `having sum(employees.id) > 0` (assuming employee id is a positive integer). It would take a little re-work of the query, but you could do it, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
select empId
from your_table
group by empId
having sum(case when type not in ('B','C') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: this is giving incorrect syntax error on second ending parenthisis at last line

Comment: Updated the answer.